# What is a Constructor in PHP Used For?

Tags: php

Before anyone says anything.  I've been to many articles, and I just can't wrap my head around the purpose of a constructor.

I've found an example on a site.  Here's the code:

```
<?php
    class dogtag {
        public $Words;
    }

    class dog {
        public $Name;
        public $DogTag;

        public function bark() {
            print "Woof!\n";
        }

        public function __construct($DogName) {
            print "Creating $DogName\n";
            $this->Name = $DogName;
            $this->DogTag = new dogtag;
            $this->DogTag->Words = "My name is $DogName. If you find me, please call 555-1234";
        }
    }

    class poodle extends dog {
        public function bark() {
            print "Yip!\n";
        }
    }

    $poppy = new poodle("Poppy");
    print $poppy->DogTag->Words . "\n";
?>
```

It echoes out the following:

```
Creating Poppy My name is Poppy. If you find me, please call 555-1234
```

May someone please explain this code to me like I'm 5.  I just don't get it.

Comment: When you create a new object (`new poodle('Poppy')`) the `__construct` function will be called. It *constructs* the object by doing whatever you tell it to do. There is not much more to it than that. What exactly is it you do not understand?

Comment: `__construct` in this case is used to dynamically define the values of class properties `public $Name;` and `public $DogTag;`, since class properties [`must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php). So since `__construct()` is executed when you create a new class object, ie. `$poppy = new poodle("Poppy");`, it allows you to dynamically set the values, instead of having to use a `constant value`

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I just can't figure out how it all wraps together.

From what I understand when I declare $poppy it effectively defines my __construct as __construct("Poppy"), then with that it starts a chain of actions that end at the: $this->DogTag->Words = "My name is $DogName. If you find me, please call 555-1234"; line.

Am I right?

Comment: @ThomasHutton Yes, you are right.

Comment: Hi there, sorry I forgot about this.  I got learning website administration.

So basically a constructor allows me to do this:

$variable = new myInfo(5); // Defines the property as 5.

As opposed to:

$property = new myInfo;
$property->limit = 5;

So it just cuts out the second line by putting it in the parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A constructor is used to do any initial process required once a new class object was initiated. Ok so that was pretty fancy right? Lets break down what that means with an example. Lets first make a class, and inside that class put some variables, some functions, and a **constructor**! *(It's easier for me to explain the concept behind a constructor with a simpler class. babysteps.)*

```
<?php

class myInfo 
{
  protected $limit;

  public function __construct($limit = 10)
  {
    $this->limit = $limit;
  }

  public function awesomesauce() {
    //...some random code...
  }

}
$variable = new myInfo();//initiating an instance of class myInfo

?>
```

The code `$variable = new myInfo();` is initiating an object of type **myInfo**. When that initiation happened, the php code knows that right away, the constructor function `public function __construct($limit = 10)` has to be called. In this case, the value of `$limit` is made to be 10. However, if I later on do the following code:

```
$variableTwo = new myInfo(20);
```

The variable passed inside the parenthesis would be passed directly into the constructor function.

So depending on the specific situation I could either pass no variables when creating an instance of type **myInfo**, in which case the constructor function would use the default value of `($limit = 10)` or I could pass a value. If php did not have the ability to use constructors, I would literally have to manually change that variable with a new line of code every time I initiated a new object of class **myInfo**. Now this is just a simple example. Imagine if you need to not only initiate values, but run functions that work with API's somewhere else on your server. You can definitely see the benefit of having this happen automatically instead of being forced to write multiple lines of code every single time an object is initiated.

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Hi there, sorry I forgot about this.  I got learning website administration.

Comment: Hi there, sorry I forgot about this.  I got learning website administration.

So basically a constructor allows me to do this:

$variable = new myInfo(5); // Defines the property as 5.

As opposed to:

$property = new myInfo;
$property->limit = 5;

So it just cuts out the second line by putting it in the parentheses?

Comment: @ThomasHutton Hi. Um not quite. You will always need to include the parenthesis `$property - new myInfo()`, The only difference is that if it is empty, the value used will be a default value. A constructor basically allows you to have a specific set of code execute whenever you declare a new object. One such example is placing initial values like limits. You might have a class that defines a queue, however you want two different queues with a different max value. The actions a constructor can preform are not limited to just setting values but anything you want really :)

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped that.  I meant to put myInfo();.

Comment: @ThomasHutton oh ok :). Oh and if this is the answer that worked for you, please accept it (with a green checkmark) so that users in the future know which answer worked for you.

Comment: But I was right.  So thanks for the help, and here have an accept!